# pythonanywhere admin site css is broken in django

Tags: django, pythonanywhere, django-admin-filters

when I deployed a django site on pythonanywhere, the admin site css got broken. It works fine on locally but on pythonanywhere it appears like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Vs7f.png)

I read the documentation on static files, ran collectstatic successfully, ran findstatic (the program finds the base.css correctly), however, I still cannot see the proper styling of the admin site.

Comment: Make sure you've got `django.contrib.admin` loaded in your `INSTALLED_APPS`, and then run `collectstatic` management command.  Also, have a look at [this help page](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles).